# How to check whether user has entered a date in the correct format?

Tags: c

How can I check whether a user has written the date into the correct format (13/04/1995)

I have tried this

```
printf("\nPlease enter the patients date of birth in the form (03/04/2013): ");

if (sizeof(scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dob.day, &dob.month, &dob.year)) < 10)
{
    printf("Error date needs to be in the format 03/04/2013.");
}
fflush(stdin);
```

But this just runs straight through?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: just a note: to clearify what is the month and what is the day, you should use values that are clear: `21/12/2013` clearly notes the first number as day while `03/04/2013` gives me no hint what is the month...

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @eckes Sorry I wrote it at the beginning in that form though...

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function returns the number of fields it read, not the number of characters. (Also, `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does.)

```
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dob.day, &dob.month, &dob.year) < 3)
{
    printf("Error date needs to be in the format 03/04/2013.");
}
```

You then have to check the range of the day, month, and year in the usual way.

---

Edit: apparently the leading zeros are important.

`scanf` reads numbers, but is more permissive than you want. However, instead of being a pedantic program, how about this?

```
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dob.day, &dob.month, &dob.year) < 3)
{
    printf("Error date needs to be in the format 03/04/2013.");
    abort();
}

/* TODO: check the date is valid */

// Put the date into the proper format
char buffer[20];
sprintf (buffer, "%02d/%02d/%d", dob.day, dob.month, dob.year);
```

The `printf` format `%02d` will write a two digit number with leading zeros, if necessary.

Comment: So this checks that every ints length is over 2 in length?

Comment: the thing is I need to make sure that `02` is correct and `2` is **not** correct even though they are both a month, under 12

Comment: No, this checks that you read 3 ints. You can't do what you want with `scanf`.

Comment: I added a suggestion how to fix the format, not just reject it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a POSIX system (and that's enough), use [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to parse the date. Otherwise you can do it like that, but remember that the return value is the number of successful conversions, not number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to read the input as a string to a buffer.
Then use `strtok()` to break the input using `/` as delimiter.
You can check the `strlen()` of each string to make sure it is in proper format.
Convert string to integers and validate all of them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d/%d/%d", ...)` return the `int` number of fields successfully scanned - hopefully 3.

Performing `sizeof (int)` likely returns 4.

---

Recommend reading the entire line into a buffer and *then* parsing it as the best approach.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOErrorOrEOF();
```

Parse the buffer.

```
char sday[3];
char smonth[3];
char syear[5];
int n;

// Only allow limited number of digits
if (sscanf(buf, "%2[0-9]/%2[0-9]/%4[0-9]%n", day, month, year, &ch) != 3 ||
    buf[n] != '\n' || 
    n != 10) {
  BadInput();
}
```

Check ranges

```
int day = atoi(sday);
int month = atoi(smonth);
int year = atoi(syear);

// adjust as needed
#define YEAR_MIN 1910
#define YEAR_MAX 2099
if (year < YEAR_MIN || year > YEAR_MAX) BadInput();

// Could do other year, month, day tests or if code has robust time functions: 

struct tm tm = { 0 };
tm.tm_year = year;
tm.tm_month = month;
tm.tm_mday = day;
// mktime() side effect: adjust y,m,d values if not in normal range
mktime(&tm);
if (tm.tm_year != year || tm.tm_month != month || tm.tm_mday != day) BadInput();
```

BTW: "(03/04/2013) " is a poor example as it does not distinguish day/month.  Suggest "31/01/2013".